# Not publishing an author photo on Elsevier journals

Tags: publications, paper-submission, publishers, elsevier

This is related to [Co-author does not want biography+photo in paper submission](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/64288/co-author-does-not-want-biographyphoto-in-paper-submission) but specific to Elsevier journals. In the mentioned question, answers showed that for IEEE they have a policy where a biography/photo could be omitted.

Can a paper be published with Elsevier, in journals which ask for an author bio/photo, without the author photo?
You can find several journals which ask for this on https://www.google.com.au/search?q=site:elsevier.com+passport-like+photo

Comment: I disagree with the "too specific" close vote: even though it is about a particular institution's regulations, Elsevier (like IEEE) is a massive institution with unified policies, and this is likely to be a simple answer about a durable policy.

Comment: Just curious... Has anyone already tried submitting a photo in which they [wear a colander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster#Headgear_in_identity_photos)?

Comment: Not seen anyone wearing a colander, though, I've always thought the author photos in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2012.2201149) are hilarious (all the authors seem to be making a "funny face" of some sort).

Answer (score 3):

**ASK THE EDITOR** prior to submission.

In practice, some Elsevier editors do accept the absense of a photo.

(That's all, folks; there is not much more to be said about it.)

Comment: Do you know if any editors refuse omitting photo/bio?

Comment: @Kimball Not known to me.

Answer (score 1):

As the author, you are certainly free to refuse to share personal details (be it the picture or biographical details). What the particular journal (or publishing venue, more in general) will do in case of refusal is up to them. They might refuse publication (unlikely, in my ignorant opinion), publish with a summary bio and no picture (i.e., "(author) is reachable at author@umiskatonic.edu" and nothing else) or just leave it out altogether (I'd guess this, if asked nicely).

Comment: I have sometimes used very atypical, but professional, photographs of myself (where I am barely recognisable).

Comment: What if the author has been in a witness protection programme? Or is someone like Greg Egan, with deliberately no photos online?